# Subversion Ignore Pattern not working too well

Tags: .net, svn, tortoisesvn

I've got the following pattern for my global ignore pattern:

```
*.pdb *.suo *.user *.cache */_ReSharper */bin */obj *.o *.lo *.la *.al .libs *.so *.so.[0-9]* *.a *.pyc *.pyo *.rej *~ #*# .#* .*.swp .DS_Store
```

resharper folders for example (_ReSharper.SubtextSolution) are still being committed as well as some other folders such as bin for some reason.

I'd also be interested to see what others have as their global ignore pattern.  Not that everyone's will apply specifically to my environment but would still be helpful to see a few regardless....specifically related to **.NET environments** that is.

Answer (score 5):

I posted this as a [response to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644653/which-files-in-a-visual-c-studio-project-dont-need-to-be-versioned/1644698#1644698), by in addition to the default TortoiseSVN global ignores I add the following:

```
.suo *.user bin obj *.pdb *.cache *_svn *.svn *.suo *.user *.build-res TestResults _ReSharper*
```

You don't need the `/` values in there.  Especially since the _Resharper folders tend to get added at the root (at least for me).

Answer (score 4):

Try using `*ReSharper*` in your ignore settings for ignoring all ReSharper files.  Also, for ignoring the bin and obj folders, I always use `[Bb]in` and `[Oo]bj`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my personal experience :

- previously commited files will keep being committed if you added the ignore pattern later (you'll have to svn-delete them explicitly)
- in tortoise svn, you should put 1 ignore pattern per line

Comment: We have had this ignore pattern in there from the start.

Comment: What do you mean by 1 ignore pattern per line?  I guess I ask because I'm specifying this in the Tortoise Settings, there is only one line.

Comment: @manitra is confused. In the ignore settings for each project, you get a different type of dialog and you specify each item on its' own line.  You are correct that in the global ignore settings, every just goes on one line space-delimited.

Comment: In tortoise svn, you can put each filename pattern on a new line. If you don't, only your first patter will be applied.

Comment: @manitra that is only correct for the per-project ignore settings. for the global ignore settings, they all just go on one line.

Comment: First point is very valid, if previously committed you will have to `svn-delete` them explicitly.

Answer (score 3):

Heres my 2 cents...

`*.o 
.lo 
.la ## ..rej .rej .~ ~ .# .DS_Store thumbs.db Thumbs.db *.bak *.class *.exe *.dll *.mine *.obj *.ncb *.lib *.log *.idb *.pdb *.ilk .msi .res *.pch *.suo *.exp .~ .~ ~. cvs CVS .CVS .cvs .datasource release Release debug Debug ignore Ignore bin Bin obj Obj [Bb]in [Oo]bj *.csproj.user *.user ReSharper. *.resharper.user  *.g.vb *.g.cs *.baml *.GenerateResource.Cache *.cache *.xap`

This covers WPF/Silverlight, WCF and Resharper along with all the usual gubbins.