# Problem with TortoiseSVN Global Ignore pattern for a Visual Studio project

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn, ignore

I'm running....

TortoiseSVN 1.6.11, Build 20210 - 64 Bit
Windows 7 64 Bit
Visual Studio 2008

I've created a repository, done an SVN Checkout, and created a new VS solution with a new project.

Next I tried to commit my changes and noticed that contents of the "bin" and "obj" directories are included in the list of items to check in.

So, I thought I would add the following expression....

```
*.suo *.user bin obj *.pdb *.cache *_svn *.svn *.suo *.user *.build-res TestResults _ReSharper*
```

.....as suggested in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644653/which-files-in-a-visual-c-studio-project-dont-need-to-be-versioned/1644698#1644698), but no joy.

What am I doing wrong????

Just to clarify, I have been right clicking the root folder of my working directory then > TortoiseSVN > Settings and adding the expression above to the "SubVersion Global Ignore Pattern"

Any help appreciated.

Many thanks,

ETFairfax

**More Info:** It's just folder references that are not working.  If I put in *.dll all dlls are omitted from the list, but I'd like to be able to put in a reference to all "bin" directories if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's mine if that helps [VS2010, c#, resharper]

```
bin obj doc *.user *.suo _ReSharper.*
```

Comment: @Dog Ears: My global ignore settings are the same as yours now, and I've typed them in to ensure spaces.  Still not working!!  It's just folder references that are the problem.  "*.dll" works, but "*/bin" doesn't.

Comment: Noticed in the docs that it's changed (i don't know how recently) so  you can simple drop the * and slashes for folders..so this should work.. see updated answer

Comment: .. also it's casesensitive.. even on windows!

Comment: if you've 'added' these folders that are *IGNORED*, they'll still show up if you're 'commiting'! The **IGNORE**, stops them appearing in the list of files to *ADD* not *COMMIT*

Comment: @DogEars: As it was a new almost empty project I ditched the lot and started again.  It's all working now.  I'm assuming is was user error along the way at some point.  Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting each entry on a separate line. Here is an example of what I use:

```
bin  
obj  
*.suo  
*.user  
*.bak
```

Answer (score 1):

Patterns aside - make sure you restart SmartSVN application. Otherwise you won't see any effect - even though your patterns may be correct.

Answer (score -1):

Bumping an old question, as the current answer has some issues.

*\bin *\bin* *\obj *\obj* *.suo *.user *.bak **.ReSharper** **_ReSharper.** StyleCop.Cache

taken from [here](http://startbigthinksmall.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/tortoise-svn-my-global-ignore-pattern-c-and-r/)